# C# When I try to call the values from my variables in my final method they are set to 0. they show correctly when they are called previously

Tags: c#, variables, methods

This is my first Program other than a Calculator, Trying to build something to track hours worked during the week.

```
public class Calculation
{
    public static int realWorkDay;
    public static float realHours;
    public static string jobDone, workDayInput, workHoursInput, workMonthInput;
    public static bool inputCorrect, dayInputCorrect;

   public static void GetHoursInput() //Function to gather information on the Hours worked
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What hours did you work on this day?");
        string workHoursInput = Console.ReadLine();
        bool inputCorrect = float.TryParse(workHoursInput, out float realHours);
        if (inputCorrect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(realHours + " Hours");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid selection.");
            GetHoursInput();
        }
      
    }

    public static void GetMonthInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What Month is this for? Example. May, Oct ");
        string workMonthInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if(workMonthInput.Length == 3) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Month of " + workMonthInput);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid selection.");
            GetMonthInput();
        }
       
    }

    public static void GetDateInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What day is this for");
        string workDayInput = Console.ReadLine();
        
        bool dayInputCorrect = Int32.TryParse(workDayInput, out int realWorkDay);
        if(dayInputCorrect)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(realWorkDay);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid selection.");
            GetDateInput();
        }
        
    }

    public static void GetJobDone() 
    { //THIS SHOWS UP AS "On 0 , You worked 0" IN CONSOLE
        Console.WriteLine("On " + workMonthInput + " " + realWorkDay + ", You worked " + realHours + " Hours");
        Console.WriteLine("What did you do on this day");
        jobDone = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
string workMonthInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

You are declaring a new local variable named `workMonthInput`.  It happens to have the same name as a field you have named `workMonthInput`, but it's a different variable.

If you meant to assign to the existing field, just remove the type declaration:

```
workMonthInput = Console.ReadLine();
```